# Where can I learn about biomechanical algorithms?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm planning to start the development of human motion recognition software which will monitor accelerations and recognize motion patterns (run, walk, jump...).

I have started collecting books about biomechanics and it would be good to get some good book about patterncomparison and detection.

Where can I get started with some reading material that might be useful for the project?

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail?  Is this motion capture or analysis of prerecorded video?

Comment: @Dave he said it "will monitor accelerations" ... I'm guessing from a portable accelerometer which the subject has on their person.

Comment: I'll use accelerometers to sample accelerations and then try to determine the type of motion by analyzing collected data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where can I get started with some reading material that might be useful for the project?

I'd suggest get started by talking with a domain expert in that domain ... and/or in a university library.

I discovered that my local university, which receives some money from the government, therefore allows anyone including non-students to obtain a library card for a small fee ... and that library is `*`enormous`*`.

As well as books, a good university library would also give you access (perhaps online access) to specialized periodicals (e.g. about biomechanics).